# Access Http server inside Genymotion

Tags: android, windows, genymotion

I have a server app using Nanohttpd as a http server inside an android app. I put it inside genymotion or bluestacks but I've been getting ip: 10.0.3.15 on both platforms. I tried the "Host-only" and "Bridged" network settings but didn't change the IP. And I can't access the http server using the ip 10.0.3.15.

Anyone have an idea on how to achieve it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use this adb command:

```
adb forward tcp:<port on your host> tcp:<port on your virtual device>
```

For example `adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080`

then connect to your host ip, on the host port. ADB will do the rest.

Now you can connect via `http://localhost:8080` in your PC.

Comment: thanks, but i no longer use Genymotion so couldn't try your solution. Appreciate it though!